# Most robust way of forwarding multiple URL via one IP

Tags: domain-name-system, routing, ip, f5-big-ip

This is probably subjective but if anyone could suggest a robust solution for the following that would be fantastic.

We have potentially multiple URL's in service which are currently 1:1 with Public IP addresses. The problem being that we will eventually run out of public IP's. Essentially they just point to servers for RDP Sessions.

we need to keep the client urls the same so adding ports to the URL is not really an option. (can DNS map an URL with no specified port to an IP with a Port somehow?)

we have an F5 load balancer but we do not have the Global Traffic manager is there some way of dishing out incoming requests to the correct internal IP via that?

In short What is the easiest way to route multiple URLs through one public IP to multiple Private IP's

Comment: Hopefully you've already deployed IPv6 and will be ready when you can no longer get IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Makes sense in the long run but i think probably not achievable for the current issue/time frame, its a legacy product we just need it working without any major upset.

Comment: I'm unclear on the specifics of what you're trying to accomplish but the F5 can do nearly anything via iRules with many examples available on devcentral.f5.com.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction, FYI i think this looks like the answer  https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/redirecting-to-different-port-based-on-url

Answer (score 0):

https://devcentral.f5.com/questions/redirecting-to-different-port-based-on-url

F5 irules apparently are the answer, only ever used this for basic load balancing so i wasnt aware of some of its more advanced features.